# Updating every row in a table based on another table

Tags: database, db2

I'm doing this update

```
UPDATE ROOM_DATE rd SET HOTEL_ID = (
    SELECT hotel_id FROM ROOM_TYPE rt WHERE rt.ROOM_TYPE_ID = rd.room_type_id
)
WHERE room_type_id < 40000 AND hotel_id IS NULL;
```

There is a table ROOM_DATE, which need a hotel_id added to it. The above query updates this id based on the hotel_id found in the ROOM_TYPE table.

This works, but it's slow. It takes an hour to execute, so I was wandering if there is a better/faster way.

Comment: How big are your tables, and do you have any indexes on them?

Comment: I don't have any indexes on, but the join is on the primary keys. room_date i 3.5M records and room_type is 300k records.

Comment: Side issue: You should regard things like auto-generated numeric ids (there's a proper term for this, but I can't think of it at the moment) as equivalent to memory addresses, and _consider them random_ (ie, having no relation to the data they act a keys for).  So stuff like `WHERE room_type_id < 40000` is only viable for 'paging' updates/deletes to keep transactions small (which is what I'm assuming you're doing here - although you shouldn't actually need a transaction in this case).

Comment: The reason I think is the select on ROOM_TYPE. It will be done at every update.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse You are right. The where clause is only there to keep the transaction short. db2 gave a transaction log filled error after 2min, if i start the the whole transaction. the `room_type_id < 40000` is to limit the amount, and `hotel_id IS NULL` is to not update where it's already done.

Comment: Can you turn journaling off for this?  If you only have this single statement running (or don't care about certain other aspects), it's not going to make a difference for repeatability (ie, you'd just run the statement again regardless).  Also, what version of DB2?  If you're on LUW, you can actually do `UPDATE table_a JOIN table_b` (or something similar) which _might_ perform better.

Comment: That are good suggestions. I'll try them out.

Answer (score 0):

You need indexes on columns you use in your joins or where-conditions. Otherwise your database will do a full-table-scan (which is slow).

So, in your case, you need indexes on:

`ROOM_DATE.ROOM_TYPE_ID`

`ROOM_DATE.HOTEL_ID`

`ROOM_TYPE.ROOM_TYPE_ID`

Comment: I tried this. The room_type_id columns are primary keys and have an index already. So I added ROOM_DATE.HOTEL_ID, but it seems this is worse. The reason I think is that I'm updating hotel_id, and the index will be recreated at every update time now.

Comment: @wistoft - it won't have to be recreated, but it will have to be updated.  The bigger problem would likely be if a large number of records only have `hotel_id IS NULL` - that's a very low cardinality, and the data would start 'shuffled' (null all sort the same, so not in the destination ordered).

Comment: I think you hit the spot there. I removed `hotel_id is NULL`, and the query excecutes at a acceptable level (around 2min for the whole table). Thank your for the help.

Answer (score 0):

So I found a way, that only takes a couple of minutes. First i export the table with the extra column (hotel_id) taken from room_type:

```
export to "./roomdate_new.data" of del modified by coldel| 
SELECT rd.ROOM_TYPE_ID, rd.single_day_date, rd.numavail, rd.numtaken, rd.price, rt.hotel_id 
FROM ROOM_TYPE rt, ROOM_DATE rd 
WHERE rt.ROOM_TYPE_ID = rd.room_type_id;
```

then I import the table again:

```
load from "./roomdate_new.data" of del modified by coldel| method P (1,2,3,4,5,6) replace  INTO ROOM_DATE;
set integrity for ROOM_DATE allow no access immediate checked;
```

But I don't think that is particularly elegant. I would have preferred a ordinary SQL statement or a procedure.